# Power bi embedded report per user via query parameter

Tags: api, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I'm looking to use power bi to embed reports int my web page.

The report data is coming from a live connection to my own API.

My API can return data per logged in user by passing the users token.

I have set up a `token` parameter on my data source URL but I need to set it dynamically per request.

How can I pass the current users token through the embedded report URL (or maybe I'm wrong, and there is an other way to do that)

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Creating a custom data connector for your API would help you with that. Would that be an option?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/startingtodevelopcustomconnectors.
and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecfRTEoYadI to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks @Dreekun How do I get the token per user from my embedded URL to the connector?

Comment: What is the authentication process? OAuth?
The connector can be programmed to request the token to the authorize endpoint, save it and refresh it. 
You can, of course, pass the token to the connector to authenticate as well. You'll need to make the connector prompt the user. Then, if it is successful authenticated, the connector feeds the reports with data from your API.